# Finding out different orbits of length n of doubling function

Tags: dynamical-systems

$$g(x)=\begin{cases}
    2x & \text{if } x \in [0,1/2] \\
    2(1-x) & \text{if } x \in (1/2,1]
    \end{cases}$$

Could you please help me to find out how many different orbits of length $n$ are possible under iteration by $g$.

Comment: Why don't you just count them?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried computing them for some $n$'s?